# Undefined reference и статическая библиотека

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

Привет!

Не могу понять одну вещь при использовании статической библиотеки.

Компилирую программу следующим образом:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp libaam.a
```

На Linux все проходит успешно, однако, при компилировании на Windows (MinGW) таким же способом получаю следующее:

```
C:\Users\cub4d\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdFjoR2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `aam::AAMEstimator::AAMEstimator()'
C:\Users\cub4d\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdFjoR2.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `aam::AAMEstimator::~AAMEstimator()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

В чем может быть причина такого разного поведения?

Comment: а случайно не используется один и тот же файл libaam.a ?

Answer (score 2):

Не компилируйте вручную, используйте систему сборки, например CMake.

Также используйте флаг `-l`, вместо передачи имени файла:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -laam
```

Comment: А что конкретно нужно прописать в CMake-файле? Пробовал через target_add_library() - не выходит

Comment: `add_library(PDCURSES STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET PDCURSES PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION E:/clion/projects/RogueLike/pdcurses.a)

target_link_libraries(RogueLike  PDCURSES)` - Такой код у меня получился после прочтения, но всё равно не верно. Что я делаю не так?